# Inertial and non-nertial observer

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, definition

Let's assume there are two observers 'A' and 'B'. B is at ground and A is moving with an uniform acceleration ('a') with respect to B. Will A be an non inertial observer with respect to B? (As we know that non inertial observers are those which are moving with an acceleration with respect to an observer).

Comment: A non-inertial observer is one who is moving with an acceleration relative to an inertial frame of reference.

Answer (score 1):

An observer is intrinsically inertial or non-inertial. Their status as inertial or non-inertial is not referred to anything else. So this question makes no sense:

> will A be an non inertial observer with respect to B?

A is either inertial or not. There is no “inertial with respect to”. Inertial or non-inertial is an invariant state, not a relative one. So the correct questions would be

> Will A be a non-inertial observer?

and

> Will B be a non-inertial observer?

Note that each question does not have a "with respect to" in the question. The observers A and B are inertial or non-inertial on their own, without any regards to any external reference frame or any other observer.

An inertial observer is one whose accelerometer (6 degree of freedom) always reads $0$. Accelerometers read invariant acceleration, also called proper acceleration. Proper acceleration is not referenced to some frame.

We know from experience that accelerometers on the ground read a proper acceleration of $- \vec g$ i.e. an acceleration of magnitude $g$ in the upwards direction. This is non-zero, so B is non-inertial.

We also know from experience that accelerometers in free fall read $0$. So if $\vec a=\vec g$ then A’s accelerometer will read $0$ and A would be inertial. If $\vec a \ne \vec g$ then A is not inertial because A’s accelerometer will read a non-zero value.

Note that $\vec a$ is not the kind of quantity that can be measured with an accelerometer. Instead, $\vec a $ would be measured with radar or something similar carried by B. So $\vec a$ is not an invariant proper acceleration. It is called a coordinate acceleration.

One caveat is that often in Newtonian physics gravity is considered a real force. Accelerometers do not detect gravitational acceleration. So in those cases you have to adjust the accelerometer reading by adding the local gravitational acceleration.

Comment: Dale is just kept telling about use of accelerometers,but during the defining of inertial frame by physicist they just do not use accelerometers,I want to know about the philosphy behind it means what is the concept behind it."for what purpose we are using an accelerometer?".and during my numerical solving in exam i will not get any accelerometer and will not perform any experiment.just want to know teachers are getting that this frame will be inertial or non inertial.

Comment: @PriyanshuChauhan we physicists absolutely do use accelerometers to determine if a frame is inertial. On an exam you need to infer what an accelerometer would read, like I did here. Sorry you don’t like the answer but this is the answer. Consider a rocket in space. When the engine is burning an accelerometer reads non-zero, so it is non-inertial. When the engine is off an accelerometer reads zero so it is inertial. We can infer that in an exam

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking that just like velocity, acceleration is also relative. Yes, we can calculate relative acceleration of an object like  a⃗ 12 =  a⃗ 1 -  a⃗ 2 as we do for velocity. But there is also an absolute acceleration of every object which does not depend on any other frame, it is intrinsic to an object. If it is zero then the frame of an object is inertial. It is measured with accelerometers. For velocity there is nothing like an absolute velocity, it is always relative.